# How do protocols for web are created & what are the specifications?

Tags: http

How are the web protocols like HTTP, FTP are created & implemented? If I decide to create a new protocol, how should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Computer/network protocols are formalized and made standards by the [IETF](http://www.ietf.org/).

- [HTTP/1.1](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt), 1999, [HTTP/1.0](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1945.txt), 1996
- [FTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959) (1985), [FTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc765) (1980)

Comment: How can you view the code for these protocols? i.e. Where is the code for FTP, FTPS, TCP, etc...?

Comment: Protocols are not software programs, they are procedures, written instructions and rules. They are what guide you, if you're writing a program that wants to talk to other programs, what the messages you exchange will look like, what order they must be sent in, etc. Here's a good example: http://www.ncftp.com/libncftp/doc/ftp_overview.html

Answer (score 0):

RFC publication process: http://www.rfc-editor.org/pubprocess.html